# Sharing FormsAuthentication Cookie Between WCF & ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, wcf, cookies, forms-authentication

For extra security I am generating a FormsAuthentication cookie in my WCF service and returning it to my web application, however I want to then utilize that cookie when making requests to particular services on WCF. How can I configure this to be passed with every request? I have setup the machine and decryption key but every time I inspect the cookies when it hits the WCF service there are no cookies to be found.

I've tried various methods to add the cookie to the header, but it seemed to make sense to just do the below because it generates and adds it to the header.

```
Return FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, False)
```

Then when I inspect the cookies on the client using...

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies
```

It's empty.

Am I doing something wrong on the client, all I am attempting is the following.

```
If AccountService.Authenticate(model.Email, model.Password) Then
    Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
End If
```

Hoping that it would just pick up the cookie in the header due to that call to the service.

I'm currently working around this in a not so ideal way, the cookie is returned in the body of the request from the service

Server

```
If CheckPassword(password, Unicode.GetString(user.Password)) And user.EmailConfirmed Then
    Return FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(email, False)
End If
```

Client

```
Dim cookie As HttpCookie = AccountService.Authenticate(model.Email, model.Password)
If cookie IsNot Nothing Then
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
    Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
End If
```

Authenticate Method (WCF)

```
Public Function Authenticate(email As String, password As String) As Boolean Implements IAccountService.Authenticate
    Dim user As [Public] = db.Publics.Where(
        Function(i) i.Email.ToLower = email.ToLower
    ).FirstOrDefault
    If Not IsNothing(user) Then
        If CheckPassword(password, Unicode.GetString(user.Password)) And user.EmailConfirmed Then
            Dim cookie As HttpCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(email, False)
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
            Return True
        End If
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: can you post the code how you generated cookie and retireived it ??

Comment: Your supposed "client" code doesn't look like a client code at all, it looks like a server code. What is your client and what is your server is not clear enough from the question, then.

Comment: @WiktorZychla My client is the web application, and the server is the WCF service.

Comment: I mean, in a WCF client you should possibly be using a proxy class that either inherits from the `ClientBase` or uses the `ChannelFactory`. The client shouldn't be using server-side APIs (`RedirectToAction`, `HttpContext`). Your client code doesn't look like one.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I'm confused, the code you're referring to is server side code (RedirectToAction). However it's still the client to the WCF service.

Comment: @WiktorZychla "If you used Visual Studio's Add Service Reference, or the svcutil.exe tool, you probably won't ever see a ChannelFactory."

Comment: So the `AccountService` is a proxy instance, isn't it? And you expect the cookie it returns be used in subsequent requests to the same service? If yes, you should not only return it from the service but also, in the WCF, add it to `Response` so that the `AccountService` has it and sends in subsequent requests.

Comment: @WiktorZychla That's my problem, when I do return it in the header it isn't passed in subsequent requests.

Comment: Could you show an excerpt of the `Authenticate` method to make sure you really add the cookie there? Also, you need to enable cookies on a service proxy in an **explicit way** by setting the `AllowCookies` to true on a binding instance e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.allowcookies(v=vs.100).aspx I bet you miss that.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I did try enabling cookies, find the method above. I do see the cookie in the response but when I call the method through the proxy class I am unable to get the cookie.